# Install Jenkins in specific folder in RHEL

Tags: linux, jenkins, installation, rhel

When we install jenkins, by default it installs at /var/lib directory in the RHEL machine. But I want to install jenkins in other folder or filesystem. for example /jenkins.
Before installing jenkins I changed JENKINS_HOME=/jenkins and tried installing jenkins but it wont work.
These are the steps which I followed to install Jenkins

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
sudo yum install jenkins
```

But the result is same it installs in /var/lib.

How can I install in /jenkins directory this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` file and change:

```
JENKINS_HOME = /var/lib/jenkins
```

to

```
JENKINS_HOME = /jenkins
```

and restart Jenkins.

Comment: Cannot find DAEMON_ARGS in /etc/init.d/jenkins